# ARP packet using target MAC

Tags: c, ip, arp

I send ARP requests to some Ip adresses but as you know a host doesn't always have the same  IP  adress.I want first to send ARP requests and save the mac adresses of the hosts that reply then to send arp packages by MAC adresses,not by IP.I managed to send ARP packets to all the hosts and to save the MAC adresses of the hosts that reply but I don't know how to send ARP packets using the target MAC adress and not the target IP adress.DO you have some suggestions ?Tell me if you want to put some code

Comment: The whole point of ARP is that it *finds out* a MAC address you don't know based on an IP that you do.

Comment: I know that but I need to monitor a host continuosly using ARP packages and sometimes the host doesn;t have the same IP so i'm asking if there is a way to send packets using MAC adress

Comment: I suggest `arpwatch`, it solves this problem, though passively, not actively. ARP only works when you know the IP, a client will _disregard_ an ARP request when the IP address of the query is not its own. (What you're looking for is a variation on RARP, but RARP requires a RARP server, so it won't work either.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the IP address of a remote host from its Ethernet address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485096/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-a-remote-host-from-its-ethernet-address)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing something up. ARP works on OSI layer 3, the MAC addresses are relevent for Ethernet on OSI layer 2. To send packages on OSI layer 3 like IP you must know the right MAC address for ethernet. So you make a broadcast (ARP request) to all stations and you'll get an answer (per usicast) with the right MAC address. Than you can send IP packages with that MAC address.

Comment: I want something like an Inverse Arp

Comment: @EmilGrigore sorry I missed your comment, for what do you need that? Maybe the command `arp -a` would help you.

Comment: @Flexo: RARP in not inverse ARP, InARP is inverse ARP, though it's used almost exclusively over ATM.

Answer (score 0):

Communicating over ARP directly is hard because there is no simple API for sending ARP messages. On Linux, you'd have to use raw sockets (see `man 7 raw`) and implement the ARP protocol yourself.

Answer (score 0):

ARP is primarily used to translate IP addresses to MAC addresses, not the other way around. Although a specification for Inverse ARP exists (translating MAC addresses to IP addresses), neither Linux, FreeBSD, or Windows machines will support it by default.

If you're trying to keep track of a machine that changes IP addresses often and you have administrative access to it, you could look into mDNS (for Linux or FreeBSD) or LLMNR for Windows. Both of these protocols allow you to query machines on the local link network by asking for their hostname. Resolve IP address via a link local version of DNS, resolve the MAC address from the IP address, and communicate away.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question correctly, You want a simple solution through which you want to send ARP msg to a specific host rather than a ARP request Broadcast.

AFAIK, There is a tool for that called "arping" which can do that but there are two versions of it comes
1. arping (part of iputils lib)
2. Thomas Habets's arping  (This allow you to send APR message directly to a dest. MAK address)

By default most of Linux have arping tool (not the Thomas Habets's arping) but you can get the Thomas Habets's arping from internet and use it the only prob is that Having both arping implementations on a system may introduce conflicts.

So to make it work properly former one have to remove and NetworkManager will also be removed, because it requires the iputils arping.

I hope this will help you.