# Retrieving Mac Address for the given IP-Address

Tags: c, linux

Is there any way to retrieve the mac-address for the given ip-address from the ARP table without providing the Interface name ??

I do know the procedure of retrieving the mac address using ioctl call but in that case I should provide the interface name .. :(

**One Crude Solution**: Read **/proc/net/arp** file ... :( .. other than that .. any system call or anything else where i can retrieve the mac-address without the need of interface name ??

**NOTE:** Simple C based solution not interested in scripting libraries.

**NOTE:** I am expecting a *NUX based solution rather than WINDOWS based one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doing ARP and Inverse ARP on Linux 2.6.21 (glibc 2.3.5)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463722/doing-arp-and-inverse-arp-on-linux-2-6-21-glibc-2-3-5)

Comment: @unwind .. the link provided by you doesn't deal anything with retrieving the mac entry from arp table programatically. I do know commandline commands like arp -a but I am looking for a solution in C.

Answer (score 1):

> I do know the procedure of retrieving
>   the mac address using ioctl call but
>   in that case I should provide the
>   interface name

So all you need is a way to find the interface name associated with a given IP. The ioctl SIOCGIFCONF will give you that.